# $xy=10$ vs $xy\geq 10$

Tags: inequality, physics, ratio

**What I understand:**

$$xy=10\tag{1}$$

Let $x,y$ be two variables. Now, if we increase the value of $x$, then the value of $y$ must decrease, to preserve the validity of $(1)$, and vice versa.

**What I don't understand:**

$$xy\geq 10$$

Let $x,y$ be two variables. If we increase $x$, I don't think $y$ needs to be decreased, but I'm not sure. Am I right?

**Context:**

I was studying Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, and it is stated below:

$$\Delta x.\Delta p\geq\frac{h}{4\pi}\ [\text{a non-zero positive constant}]$$

$\Delta x$ is the uncertainty in position and $\Delta p$ is the uncertainty in momentum/speed (since mass is constant). My book said that the smaller the $\Delta x$, the larger is the $\Delta p$, and vice versa. I would've had no problem with accepting the previous sentence if Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle was $\Delta x.\Delta p=\frac{h}{4\pi}$, instead of what it is.

Comment: You are correct in saying that as we *increase* $x$, $y$ doesn't need to be decreased. However, the textbook is saying that the *smaller* the $\Delta x$ (i.e. as we *decrease* $\Delta x$), then $\Delta p$ needs to increase to keep their product above $\frac{h}{4\pi}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative, and consider the inequality $xy\ge 10$. Then

- if you *increase* $x$, and $y$ remains the same, then the inequality is still true;
- the *smaller* $x$ is (than its current value), the larger must $y$ be (than its current value).

No contradiction.

---

For example, for $x=5,y=2$, the inequality is true.

- If $x=11$ and $y=2$, the inequality is still true.
- If $x=1$, which is *smaller* than $5$, $y$ must be at least $10$, which is larger than $5$.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand. Isn't it possible though in $$xy\geq10$$ to decrease $x$ without invalidating the inequality? For example, if $x=10, y=10$, the inequality is true. If we decrease $x$ to $x=9$, the inequality is still true and $y$ doesn't need to be decreased, right?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic: that special case is right. The problem is that you want a general statement that is *always* true.